# scope variable is deleted with ng-model-options when $validators return false

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the fiddle of my problem.
It is very simple... it seems like angular encounters a problem.

http://plnkr.co/edit/5diCIhFoWX8FneSSBkfA?p=preview

**Description:**

I'm using ng-model-options, so that to model only gets updated when there is a blur event on the input.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myText" ng-model-options="{ updateOn : 'blur' }">
```

This works fine, but when I add a directive to trigger $validators the `myText` scope variable dissapears when the `$validators` returns false.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myText" ng-model-options="{ updateOn : 'blur' }" check-errors>
```

**Directives**

```
.directive('checkErrors', function(){

  return {

    require : 'ngModel',
    link : function(){

          ngModel.$validators.validHour = function(modelValue){
                return true;
          };
    }
  };

});
```

To see the problem, change `return true;` to `return false;` change input and create the blur event.

**Edit**
new Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/5diCIhFoWX8FneSSBkfA?p=preview

I thought it should be inside an ng-repeat to trigger the issue, but that's not the case.

Comment: Use [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) to create demo

Comment: Thank you for the link. The question has been edited with the link in it. It is very easy to understand with the fiddle.

Comment: really not sure why. Does the same thing if use built in validators like `type="email"`

Comment: I just made another edit. If i delete my validator, there will just be an input with type="email"... so that works yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this is correct behavior in Angularjs, which means what would you like to do instead?

Here are a few options...

By adding **allowInvalid: true** to your options, will present with your text being rendered, but then you are negating the validation.

Check out the updated plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/5I8T2P670sTq5EA6ktTR?p=preview)

```
ng-model-options="{ updateOn : 'blur', allowInvalid: true }"
```

**UPDATE**

Trying to find $validators in Angular code base, perhaps this has something to do with it as correct behavior.

[code base $validtors](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngModel.js#L22)

```
ctrl.$$runValidators(modelValue, viewValue, function(allValid) {
  // If there was no change in validity, don't update the model
  // This prevents changing an invalid modelValue to undefined
  if (!allowInvalid && prevValid !== allValid) {
    // Note: Don't check ctrl.$valid here, as we could have
    // external validators (e.g. calculated on the server),
    // that just call $setValidity and need the model value
    // to calculate their validity.
    ctrl.$modelValue = allValid ? modelValue : undefined;
```

Looks like the ctrl.$modalValue is getting set to the update only if the model passes validation, or it gets **undefined**, which is why your

```
        <pre> {{ appCtrl.test }} </pre>
```

is disappearing on you. There is no value to present.

Comment: Thank you. I think default should be `true`