# Understanding scope in directive's childs

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to understand "scopes" in agularJS and i can't understand the following piece of code:

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myModule">

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <my-component>
        <h2>Attribute</h2>
        {{isolatedAttributeFoo}}
    </my-component>

    <my-component>
        <h2>Attribute</h2>
        {{isolatedAttributeFoo}}
    </my-component>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

AngularJS:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', [])
.directive('myComponent', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope:{}
    };
})
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.isolatedAttributeFoo = 'Hello!';
}]);
```

As you can see it is a very simple test. As far as i know (from [this](http://jsfiddle.net/simpulton/SPMfT/) example), the childs of a directive (in the example, the elements inside "my-component") inherit the scope from the directive and, since the "my-component" scope is isolated, the "isolatedAttributeFoo" variable should NOT take the value from the "isolatedAttributeFoo" variable at the controller... But it does. Why? Am i misunderstanding something?

If you want to try it, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kst65t0p/) is the Fiddle.

Comment: You are using the parent variable. The child one exists only inde the directive, and can be printed inside the template.

Comment: Ok Fals and @charlietfl, but why in this Fiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/SPMfT/429/ it behaves like the childs inside the directive inherit the isolated scope of the directive, without the need of using "template" or "templateURL"?

Comment: that fiddle is using angular 1.01 which is too old to test anything anymore. I don't think isolated scope was even available then

Comment: Well, it should, as that example was taken from a tutorial to understand the scopes in directives. But you are right, too old to worry about it. Thanks!

Comment: also understand that the whole framework has matured significantly since then...so would be wary of old tutorial like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only isolate the scope when you include the `template` or `templateUrl` in the directive definition. Other wise it will only inherit from parent and view won't even recognize any changes to scope made in link or controller of directive

Try the following:

HTML

```
<my-component></my-component>
```

JS

```
.directive('myComponent', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        template: ' <h2>Attribute</h2>{{isolatedAttributeFoo}}',
        scope:{},
        link:function(scope){
           scope.isolatedAttributeFoo = 'Good Bye!';
        }
    };
});
```

<kbd>[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kst65t0p/2/)</kbd>

Comment: This has nothing to do with this question, but could you find out this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31595970/scope-variable-is-deleted-with-ng-model-options-when-validators-return-false

Answer (score -1):

I think this will be clear:

Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/kst65t0p/3/

```js
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', [])
    .directive('myComponent', function () {
        return {
            restrict:'E',
            scope:{},
            link : function(scope){
               alert(scope.isolatedAttributeFoo);
            }
        };
    })
    .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function () {
        this.isolatedAttributeFoo = 'Hello!';        
    }]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <my-component>
        <h2>Attribute</h2> {{MyCtrl.isolatedAttributeFoo}}
    </my-component>
            
    <my-component>
        <h2>Attribute</h2> {{MyCtrl.isolatedAttributeFoo}}
    </my-component>
</div>









<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Your scope is isolated into the link function.
The link function is to a directive what a controller is to the view.